# Reference Any Attribute with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to set all attributes in a table at once using Entity Framework, with a DbSet, in ASP.NET MVC4. The repository does not know all the attributes, but I am sure the controller & view are passing all the correct attributes (separation of concerns goodness). How do I reference a generic attribute of the table with a DbSet?

Here is an example:

MyRepository.cs:

```
public class MyRepository {
    private EFMyContext context = new EFMyContext();

    public IQueryable<Entity> Tables { get { return context.Tables; } }

    public void SaveEntity(Entity entity) {
        Table savedRow = context.Tables.Find(entity.ID);
        foreach(attribute in Attribute attributes) { // how do I call these attributes?
            // update attributes
        }
    }
}
```

MyController.cs:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private EFMyRepository repo;

    public ViewResult Save(Entity entity) {
        repo.SaveEntity(entity);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by 'attributes'? Are you trying to update the properties of an entity? And DbSet is a feature of Entity Framework rather than LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: @LeeD, I mean the attributes of the table. I'm not sure what they're translated into in the DbSet.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without external tools?

Comment: WLeeD, I changed Linq to Entity. Sorry, I'm new to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all of the attributes using the information you have in your `entity` instance, I would recommend injecting them using  http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ .

In your code, you would then call

```
savedRow.InjectFrom(entity);
```

And it would match attributes with the same name and type and update them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoMapper, similar to ValueInjecter, but some say is better.